# Crossfade Background images using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to crossfade/transition background images through hovering the element. Is is possible?
I have a `DIV` element that has a background image but when you hover it, the background image changes with a transition/crossfade effect. On my Stylesheet i have assigned a class for hover state.

Here is the normal or non-hover state of `DIV`.

```
#crossfade DIV{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url('img/bg.jpg');
}
```

Below is the hover state class of `DIV`.

```
#crossfade DIV.hovered{
    background-image: url('img/bg-1.jpg');
}
```

Then my jquery script below:

```
$(function(){
    $('#crossfade').find('DIV').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('hovered');
    }, function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hovered');
    });
});
```

My script just simple switch the background image. Now what i want is to give it a transition effect or more like fadeIn/fadeOut effect. Like as the previous background image is fading out, the next background image is also fading In.

Any idea how to do this? Is it possible?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent quite some time troubleshooting this as it interested me as well. Learnt a lot so thought I'd share it with you.

First: I don't believe you can **cross-fade** background images using *addClass* and *removeClass* because **you can't logistically fade an element in and out at the same time**. (If I'm wrong about this please someone school me).

Just so that you know that I know what you're wanting, I successfully got the following to work:

```
$(".div-bkgrnd-1").hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut("slow",function() {
        $(this).addClass('div-bkgrnd-2').fadeIn("slow",function() {
            $(this).removeClass('div-bkgrnd-1');
        });
    });
});
```

However, this **DOESN'T** resolve your issue, which is creating a **cross-fade** of 2 images.

You will see that the *fadeOut* runs first, then the new class is added, then the *fadeIn* is run, and the first class is removed. You can't run the *fadeOut* and *fadeIn* (which would create the cross-fade you're looking for) at the same time because if you remove the first class before the *fadeOut* is finished, it interrupts the animation.

Here is a solution that I believe will work for you.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div1"> <!-- with CSS background-image applied -->
    <img id="img" />
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#div1").hover(function() {
    $("#img").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

**Note:** Be sure to target the div for your hover function; targeting the image results in some bizarre behaviour.

(This solution assumes you wanted the image to crossfade when you hover and then crossfade back to the original when you un-hover. Changing the function to fadeOut will work as a once-off if that's what you want).

If you were specifying **background images** because you need other content to sit in front, this is easily solved using z-index and a containing div (plus the jQuery above).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div1">
        <img id="img" />
    </div>
    <div id="div2>
        Some content here to appear over the top of "div1".
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#div1 {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: image1;
}

#div2 {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are libraries like the jQuery cycle plugin that can do this for you. Very powerful and easy to use. You can also roll your own using callbacks though. I believe this will work - I only coded the first half, but I think you will get the idea.

```
$(function(){
    $('#crossfade').find('DIV').hover(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(this).addClass('hovered').fadeIn();
    });
    }, function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hovered');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about not involving jQuery at all since you're willing to use CSS3?

Simple solution.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <img src="img1hover.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container div { 
    background-image: url("img1.jpg");
}
#container div img {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 500ms opacity;
    -moz-transition: 500ms opacity;
    -ms-transition: 500ms opacity;
    -o-transition: 500ms opacity;
    transition: 500ms opacity;
}
#container div img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**Note:** `-webkit`, `-moz`, `-ms` and `-o` prefixes are only to avoid compabilty issues, but it should work just fine in all modern browsers.

Stripped version:

```
#container div { 
    background-image: url("img1.jpg");
}
#container div img {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 500ms opacity;
}
#container div img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Only downside is that background image won't fade out, it will be overlayered with `img` element, so it's useless with transparent PNGs.