# Fade in a class before fading out completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, fadein, fadeout

I would like to change an image in my site with fading effect. The thing is that I am using two different classes for the same div, so actually I want to fade out one class and in the meanwhile start fading in the second class, before the first one has been completely removed.

HTML:

```
 <div id="background_image" class="day"></div>
```

CSS:

```
 .day{
      background: url(day.png);
  }

 .night {
     background: url(night.png);
 }
```

JQuery:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    if($("#background_image").hasClass("day")){
        $("#background_image").fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("day");  
        });

        $("#Landscape").fadeIn(function() {
            $(this).addClass("night");  
        });
    }else{
           $("#background_image").fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("night");  
        });

        $("#Landscape").fadeIn(function() {
            $(this).addClass("day");  
        });
    }
}, 5000);
```

But this code makes the image "day.png" first to disappear completely and then the "night.png" comes which is not what I want.
Is there a way to fade out the class "day" and start fade it "night" without having a blank space between the fading? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you're trying to do is cross-fading. This is normally done using 2 divs. If this is for the entire background, then I suggest http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/. You can take a look at their implementation to narrow it down to just a div if you don't need it to cover the entire background.

This is how I solved it for a similar case.

```
var images = [
   "/content/images/crane1.jpg",
   "/content/images/crane2.jpg",
   "/content/images/crane-interior.jpg"
];
// The index variable will keep track of which image is currently showing
var index = 0;

// Call backstretch for the first time,
// In this case, I'm settings speed of 500ms for a fadeIn effect between images.
$.backstretch(images[index], { speed: 500 });

// Set an interval that increments the index and sets the new image
// Note: The fadeIn speed set above will be inherited
setInterval(function () {
    index = (index >= images.length - 1) ? 0 : index + 1;
    $.backstretch(images[index]);
}, 5000);
```

EDIT:
For non-full background, take a look at this post [Crossfade Background images using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206440/crossfade-background-images-using-jquery)

Also take a look at this, might be closer to your scenario [Cross fade background-image with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346577/cross-fade-background-image-with-jquery)

Comment: no it is not the whole background just a part of it. But I would like not to use any plugin if possible.

Comment: Thank you I used the the code from here http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/simple-jquery-image-crossfade/ after searching for cross fading. And works perfect. Thanks again